# If a ball bounces from a wall, then when (if ever) does it bounce upwards, rather than "loses energy"?

Tags: classical-mechanics

If a ball bounces from a wall, then when (if ever) does it bounce upwards, rather than "loses energy"?

I.e. when does the following occur?

This is simulated using "bouncing ball equation" and the direction change is merely about making $x+\Delta x$ to $x- \Delta x$.

[image]

In the plot the colors don't matter (it's just default matplotlib to plot in different colors). There's a non-visualized wall at $x=15$. The last dot is over, since with this chosen $t$, the last plot before turn ends up $x > 15$.

Comment: @user47014 Because bouncing upwards implies "increase in energy"? When intuition says that "perhaps there should be loss of energy?".

Comment: @user407014 Do you imply that "bouncing downwards" never occurs? Maybe the direction is related to whether the ball has passed the peak or not?

Comment: @user47014 Is it impossible to make it bounce upwards if the angle is downwards? I assume that this is something related to the direction of the force where the ball travers. But perhaps it's not possible unless there's a change in gravity?

Comment: Because momentum must be conserved in both the horizontal and vertical directions, it is also true for particles that when they bounce, the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection.  This fact highly constrains what a bouncing ball can do.

Comment: I don't know the proper physics-y way to express this, but _real_ balls have finite size, and they have angular momentum, and when a ball makes glancing contact with a wall or a floor, there can be a significant transfer of linear momentum to angular momentum or vice versa, causing bounces that may be surprising to anybody who has not played a lot of raquet sports.

Comment: I have no idea what those coloured dots are supposed to be graphing.

Comment: @JMac, I suspect that the OP is running a simplistic computer simulation. Each dot plots the position in two dimensions of a particle (a.k.a., "ball") at a particular point in time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm still _very_ confused how that plot relates to the rest of the question.  (also very confused why they would make the plots with different coloured dots, like do all the orange dots represent something different than the light blue ones?  That's more of a terrible graph issue an less related to the physics though)

Comment: @Jmac Sorry if they confuse you. It's just matplotlib's default way of plotting. That it plots each new input as separate color.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a frictionless*, perfectly elastic bounce, then bouncing off a vertical surface won't change the vertical component of the ball's motion.  If it was moving upward when it hit the wall, it still will be moving upward as it bounces away. If it was moving downward when it hit the wall, then it still will be moving downward after the bounce.

---

* See my comment about "angular momentum" (a.k.a., "spin") of "*real*" balls on your question.